# SQL Server error: the INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I know this may sound dumb to ask but I have trouble with these tables, I know they are wrong but I don't know how to fix them.

This is my code:

```
create table Empresarial
(
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    Alojamiento varchar(10),
    correo varchar(15),
    nlineas int,
    precio decimal(7,2),
    constraint pk_paquete_empresarial primary key(paquete)
);

create table Telefono
(
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    nllamadas varchar(15),
    precio decimal(7,2),
    constraint pk_paquete_telefono primary key(paquete)
);

create table TVTel
(
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    nllamadas varchar(15),
    canales varchar(10),
    TVS varchar(10),
    precio decimal(7,2),
    constraint pk_paquete_tvtel primary key(paquete)
);

create table TV
(
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    canales varchar(10),
    TVS varchar(10),
    precio decimal(7,2),
    constraint pk_paquete_tv primary key(paquete)
);

create table Paquete
(
    IDContrato int not null,
    TipoCon varchar (11) not null,
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    constraint pk_IDContrato primary key(IDContrato),
    constraint fk_paquete_empresarial foreign key (paquete) references Empresarial(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_telefono foreign key (paquete) references Telefono(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_tvtel foreign key (paquete) references TVTel(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_tv foreign key (paquete) references TV(paquete)
);
```

Here are my Inserts:

```
insert into Empresarial 
values ('EMPPAQ001', 'SI', 'SI', 50, 1499.00);

insert into Telefono 
values ('TELPAQ001', '1000', 249.00);

insert into TV 
values ('TVSPAQ001', '52', 1, 289.00);

insert into TVTel 
values ('TVTPAQ001', '1000', '52', 1, 329.00); 

insert into Paquete 
values (1001, 'Mensual', 'TVTPAQ001'), 
       (1002, 'Mensual', 'TVSPAQ001'),
       (1003, 'Mensual', 'TELPAQ001'),
       (1004, 'Mensual', 'EMPPAQ001');
```

The thing is, I want to reference 4 primary keys from 4 different tables to one column in another table as a foreign keys. I get this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_paquete_empresarial". The conflict occurred in database "telecommsouthtest", table "dbo.Empresarial", column 'paquete'.

when I do some inserts in the table `Paquete`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the INSERT statement you are using as part of creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Each of your four tables would need to have that value in their `paquete` columns for you to be able to insert it into the `Paquete` table's `paquete` column..

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Here are my inserts: 
insert into Empresarial values ('EMPPAQ001','SI','SI',50,1499.00);
insert into Telefono values ('TELPAQ001','1000',249.00);
insert into TV values ('TVSPAQ001','52',1,289.00);
insert into TVTel values ('TVTPAQ001','1000','52',1,329.00); 

select * from Empresarial;

insert into Paquete values (1001,'Mensual','TVTPAQ001'),(1002,'Mensual','TVSPAQ001'),(1003,'Mensual','TELPAQ001'),(1004,'Mensual','EMPPAQ001');

Comment: @ps2goat I know, I have already those values in each of my four tables, the problem comes when I do an insert in the Paquete table. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your final table definition:

```
create table Paquete
(
    IDContrato int not null,
    TipoCon varchar (11) not null,
    paquete varchar(10) not null,
    constraint pk_IDContrato primary key(IDContrato),
    constraint fk_paquete_empresarial foreign key (paquete) references Empresarial(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_telefono foreign key (paquete) references Telefono(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_tvtel foreign key (paquete) references TVTel(paquete),
    constraint fk_paquete_tv foreign key (paquete) references TV(paquete)
);
```

You have stated that, in every row, `paquete` MUST match the `paquete` column in **all 4 other tables**. NOT at least one of them, but ALL of them.

You can't have a foreign key reference from one table to match one of many tables. Each "constraint" is required on that column in every row.

Comment: So that means my design is not in the way it should be?